# What is the わ in 忌まわしい and 嘆かわしい?

Tags: etymology, morphology

On [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8891660#8891660), Chocolate helped me find some examples of adjectives produced from verbs using the [`しい`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%97%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=11&index=108112300000) suffix.  In the following examples, it appears to attach directly to the 未然形:

> 勇む　　→　　勇ま　＋　しい
>       悩む　　→　　悩ま　＋　しい
>       喜ぶ　　→　　喜ば　＋　しい
>       妬む　　→　　妬ま　＋　しい
>       呪う　　→　　呪わ　＋　しい
>       慕う　　→　　慕わ　＋　しい
>       好む　　→　　好ま　＋　しい
>       好む　　→　　好も　＋　しい
>       頼む　　→　　頼も　＋　しい

But in these last two examples, there seems to be an extra `わ` inserted:

> 嘆く　　→　　嘆か　＋　わ　＋　しい
>       忌む　　→　　忌ま　＋　わ　＋　しい

I can't seem to find a dictionary entry for `わ` or `わしい`.  What is this `わ`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `わ` in these words is actually the 未然形 of the [継続の助動詞「ふ」](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5), which historically attached to the 未然形 of other verbs.  In this case, the combination of `嘆く` and `ふ` formed the verb `嘆かふ`, and the combination of `忌む` with `ふ` produced `忌まふ`.  It is these words that combined with the `し` suffix:

> [嘆かふ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B5)　　→　　嘆かは　+　し
>   [忌まふ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E5%BF%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%B5&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss)　　→　　忌まは　+　し

In modern Japanese, the `は` becomes `わ`, and the classical 終止形 `し` is replaced with the 連体形 `しき`, which loses its /k/ and becomes `しい`:

> 嘆かは　+　し　　　→　　　嘆かわ　+　しい
>   忌まは　+　し　　　→　　　忌まわ　+　しい

So as you can see, these words aren't really exceptions.  Your list includes `呪う` and `呪わしい`, and that word can be explained in the same way.  And in all of these examples, the suffix `しい` is attaching directly the 未然形 of a verb.

By the way, there's some interesting discussion in English of the auxiliary `ふ` in [this blog post on tumblr](http://bottlegrotto.tumblr.com/post/1117231887/o-repetition-and-continuation-auxiliary-verb).

Comment: @summea See [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  I worked this out on the chat, and jkerian suggested I post it as a question anyway, so I did! :-)

Comment: The details on ふ are correct, but rather beside the point. Consider 叩く vs. 戦う. The later is simply tatak-a-fu > tatak-a-[w]u, via the same ふ. Similarly, 嘆く and 忌む are beside the point. It is verb 忌まう (formally 忌まふ) and 嘆かう (formally 嘆かふ) which correspond to adjective 忌まわしい (formally 忌まはし) and 嘆かわしい (formally 嘆かはし).

Comment: @Dono, a minor point, but I think you mean "form*er*ly" instead of "form*al*ly" -- the ふ and は spellings are considered obsolete since the spelling reforms after WWII, and these aren't used in formal writing.  They might still get used in poetic writing or in other deliberately archaic contexts, but I haven't run across them in modern formal contexts.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link for the 呪う example, which I needed to think about for a bit to understand. https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AE%E3%82%8D%E3%81%B5