# Iterative / repetitive る evolving from classical 連体形【れんたいけい】

Tags: verbs, etymology, conjugations, history, morphology

This is somewhat related to the discussion of classical auxiliary verb ふ, mentioned in the answer to snailboat's question, [What is the わ in 忌まわしい and 嘆かわしい?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11678/what-is-the-%E3%82%8F-in-%E5%BF%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-and-%E5%98%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%84).

Another apparent iterative / repetitive ending that I've bumped into is る, attaching not to the 未然形【みぜんけい】 but instead to the old 終止形【しゅうしけい】.  This suffix shows up much less often.  Examples that come to mind are まく・まくる and むく・むくる, but I think there may be a few more that escape me at the moment.  According to Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* dictionary, this form appears to have evolved from the classical 連体形【れんたいけい】, formed by adding る onto the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 for 二段{にだん} and 一段{いちだん} verbs (both 下{しも} and 上{かみ}).  (I almost listed あく・あくる above, but I realized that あくる here is still restricted to 連体-only usage.)

Does anyone have any information on the process whereby this 連体形 form evolved into an apparent iterative/repetitive?  Alternatively, does anyone have any explicit explanation of this formation and its semantic uses?

Comment: Are you aware that "iterative" and "repetitive" are terms for forms of aspect? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Re: aspect, yes. Have a look at the linked thread, that mentions the repetitive / continuative aspect conveyed by the auxiliary ふ. This る seems similar, but much more limited in use.

Comment: As you found out, まくる and むくる are the 連体形 of まく and むく. Their structure is _mak-uru_ and _muk-uru_, rather than _mak-u-ru_ and _muk-u-ru_ because 終止形 is an inflectional suffix, and aspectual affixes are usually derivational. But it is rare for a derivational suffix to follow an inflectional one. Also note that the first /u/ of the _-uru_ was replaced by /e/ because these verbs are 下二段. There is nothing especially iterative or repetitive about the 連体形 of the above verbs. The property resides in their lexical aspect.

Comment: @ThomasGross -- 1) まく is a 五段 verb that apparently evolved from a 四段 verb, and as such, the 連体形 would be まく, not まくる.  Likewise for むく.  Also, although both root verbs apparently had 下二段 variants, these are the intransitive forms, whereas the 四段 forms and the -る forms are transitive.  I am left thinking that this -る is not the usual 連体形.  2) Not sure what you mean by *aspectual affixes are usually derivational.*  Could you expand on that?  Do you mean similar to how iterative / continuative ふ may have derived from あふ?

Comment: It has been known at least since Bybee 1985 that the morphemes after the verb appear in a specific order: valence - voice - aspect - tense, etc. Iterative, progressive, repetitive, etc. express aspect. Note that aspect is closer to the verb than tense. Your assumption reverses that, and thus goes against the grain of established knowledge. Up until and including aspect, morphemes are derivational suffixes, from tense on, they become inflectional suffixes. In Japanese, a derivational suffix cannot follow an inflectional suffix. See the paper by Narrog, (Journal) Morphology 2010 vol20/1.

Comment: It seems we may be talking past each other, and there are some things I realize I haven't been clear about.  1) I'm fine with the explanation that this -る is not an iterative, and that the iterative sense is supplied by the underlying verb.  2) That said, what is this -る?  It does not appear to be the usual 連体形, in that the -る form of the 連体形 only applies to 二段 and 一段 verbs, and as noted above, the transitivity is all wrong for まく・まくる and むく・むくる for this -る to be a regular 連体形.  Also, 二段 generally evolves into 一段, as did the normal 二段 forms of まく and むく, whereas this -る is 五段.  So what is it?

Comment: I still don't understand which period you're talking about. For instance, there is no verb _mukuru_ in contemporary Japanese. Else, please provide an example. I think your confusion simply stems from your disinclination to segment the verbs. The fact that you use kana instead of a phonematic segmentation seems to hint that you don't really understand how Japanese verbs are segmented. You may want to take a closer look at Suzuki Shigeyuki's work ([here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%88%B4%E6%9C%A8%E9%87%8D%E5%B9%B8)). I also believe that your question would improve if you provided examples.

Comment: まくる is in modern usage, and shows up in compounds like やりまくる, "to do something over and over again", or いいまくる, "to talk up a storm, to go on and on".  For kanji usage, it's often spelled 捲る, further implying 巻く (alt spelling 捲く with the 手偏) + る.  If Shogakukan is accurate, this verb is 五段 and transitive, evolving directly from 四段.  むくる is an additional reading for 剥る, apparently also read as はつる, へずる, and へつる.  Digging around for this one, it's only listed as 四段, so it's obsolete.  That said, it seems to exhibit the same pattern of むく (四段他動) → むくる (四段他動).

Comment: Another possible example is 漏{く}く (四段自動) → modern 潜{くぐ}る (五段自動 and formerly read as くくる).

Comment: "Phonematic" is a new term for me.  Re-reading this thread, I *think* you're suggesting that I should use romaji to more clearly show conjugational root boundaries.  If so, まく *mak-u* → まくる *makur-u*.  If this were an outgrowth of the regular 連体形 for 下二段 verbs, the expected form would be *maku-ru*, then replacing the first /u/ with /e/ to produce *make-ru*.  Moreover, as far as I've learned, 下二段 verbs all uniformly become 下一段 verbs in modern Japanese.  But *makur-u* is instead a 五段 verb, evolving from earlier 四段 *makur-u*.

Comment: Yes. I believe romanji would be better here. You're correct that _makur-u_ is 五段 deriving from 四段 (my present [source](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B) top lemma, in particular no. 5). I'm not entirely sure, though, that we're not dealing with a compound based on _kur-u_ ([here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B) fourth from the top). Presently, I have no means to verify that. Can you check it out?

Comment: Possible prefixing with *ma-* or something similar instead: that is an interesting possibility.  I do note, however, that a number of the meanings of *mak-u* (「布、または紙などを、一端を軸として、くるくると丸くする。」、「種を散らし植える。」) have overlap with *makur-u* (「端をまいて上げる。」、「追い散らす。」).  The "winding" theme is in common with *kur-u*, but the "scattering" theme seems separate.  Perhaps *makur-u* represents some kind of fusion of the two verbs *mak-u* and *kur-u*, somehow not exhibiting the expected form of *makikur-u*?  I'll do some digging, see what I can find.

Comment: Could this be a case of mistaken analogy with some other word, as with うたがわしい and いかがわしい?

Comment: @John, I'm not sure -- I don't quite understand your question?  Are you asking about _makuru_ possibly being confused with something else?

Comment: Just as a fun example of this in (somewhat) contemporary usage: 「歳月流るる如し」
Although it is probably more common to say 「歳月人を待たず」 I would guess

Comment: @derpda, that's actually something different.  :)  That 流るる is the normal classical 連体形 of 流る, a verb with the 下二段 conjugation pattern.  This 流る is the classical 終止形 or dictionary form of modern 流れる, a verb with the 下一段 conjugation pattern.  Meanwhile, in the question, まく and まくる are each of them both the classical and modern 終止形 of two distinct verbs, both with the 四段 conjugation pattern in classical Japanese, and the 五段 conjugation pattern in modern Japanese.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Ok I'm gonna be real with you, that went way over my head. But it was interesting anyway! Hope you'll get your answer!

Comment: @derpda, no worries, we all come from different levels! :) Looking at it differently, I may be in too deep.  If you're interested in classical Japanese, the JA Wikipedia has decent articles about the conjugation paradigms, such as the [下二段活用](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) page. Cheers!